# Problems while creating bigquery table schema

Tags: arrays, json, schema, google-bigquery

Using Google BigQuery I need to manually create a table and load the data contained in the json file. I am using BigQuery UI, but unable to define the schema for the data, a sample of the same is given below. The problem comes with the json array as below.

```
{"Author": "Pranesh Nageshwar", "headline": "Train trashes crashed car", "charactercount": 1027, "dateLive": "2014-01-14", "keywords": ["train crash", "freight train", "online reporting page", "side road", "blue mountains", "new south wales", "australia", "blaxland", "new south wales", "australia", "crime stoppers", "springwood police station", "train tracks"], "id": "1226801299367"}
```

Comment: like Pentium10 says.... what's your issue? What did you try? At this point it seems like you don't know what to do, but haven't tried anything....

Comment: So for above example I have tried giving in schema as below, but it doesn't work :

Comment: Author:STRING, headline:STRING, charactercount:INTEGER, keywords:RECORD, id:STRING       . It gives me error as unidentified type "RECORD".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays of values in BigQuery are represented as a field with a repeated mode.  The schema you want is probably the following.  If you copy and paste this into the box in the web UI, I think it will work.

```
[
  {
    "name": "author",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "headline",
    "type": "string"
  },
  {
    "name": "charactercount",
    "type": "integer"
  },
  {
    "name": "dateLive",
    "type": "string",
  },
  {
    "name": "keywords",
    "type": "string",
    "mode": "repeated"
  },
  {
    "name": "id",
    "type": "string"
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried the above, though got below error :    Field:dateLive, Could not parse '2014-01-01' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]  . It means control didn't even reach till the array. Though it works if I change it from type as timestamp to STRING.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the timestamp issue.  Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Thanks for the help, above solution serves the purpose.